# How to manipulate two select fields and dynamically change textContent

Tags: javascript, html-select

I have two selects.
    The first one displays `male` of `fem` and the second one display names depending on chosen `mal` or `fem` option. It works well. But I want to display these values in the new div. However, I can only access the `mal` or `fem` option. I guess it's because it is THIS. But how to add to this textContent a name? For example, create a `div` with textContent  `male James` or `fem Lola` ? See code and link below

```
const namesArr = {
     male: ['Tom', 'James', 'John', 'Jimmy', 'Angelo', 'Patrick', 'Ron'],
     fem: ['Jemma', 'Samantha', 'Lola', 'Penny', 'Mary']
 }

function show(){  
    document.querySelector('#name').textContent = ''
    document.querySelector('.result').textContent = ''

 let val = this.value

  for(let i of Object.keys(namesArr)) {

    if(val === i) {

   namesArr[i].forEach(elem => {
         newElem.value = i
         newElem.textContent = elem;
         document.querySelector('#name').style.display = 'inline-block'
         document.querySelector('#name').append(newElem)             
         document.querySelector('.result').textContent = 
         this.options[this.selectedIndex].textContent               
       });
     }
  }
}
document.querySelector('#sex').addEventListener('click', show);
```

[Link to JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a1dqm36p/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to add event listener name select too

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qh2urt18/)

```js
const namesArr = {
  male: ['Tom', 'James', 'John', 'Jimmy', 'Angelo', 'Patrick', 'Ron'],
  fem: ['Jemma', 'Samantha', 'Lola', 'Penny', 'Mary']
}

function show(){  
   document.querySelector('#name').textContent = ''
   document.querySelector('.result').textContent = ''
 
  let val = this.value
 
      for(let i of Object.keys(namesArr)) {
    
       if(val === i) {
   
       namesArr[i].forEach(elem => {
           let newElem = document.createElement('option');
           newElem.value = i
           newElem.textContent = elem;
          document.querySelector('#name').style.display = 'inline-block'
          document.querySelector('#name').append(newElem)   
            
          document.querySelector('.result').textContent = this.options[this.selectedIndex].textContent   
            
           });
       }
    }
}
function nameChange(){
var sexDDL = document.getElementById("sex");
var sex = sexDDL.options[sexDDL.selectedIndex].text;
 document.querySelector('.result').textContent = sex +" "+this.options[this.selectedIndex].textContent 
}
document.querySelector('#name').addEventListener('click', nameChange);

document.querySelector('#sex').addEventListener('click', show);
```

```html
<select name="sex" id="sex">
  <option value="male">Male</option>
  <option value="fem">Feminine</option>
</select>
<select name="name" id="name"></select>

<div class="result"></div>
```